Showing surface integral vanishes at infinity - extinction theorem
Suppose the dyadic Green's function $\overline{G}$ is defined as
\begin{equation} 
    \overline{G}(r, r') = \left(\overline{I} + \frac{\nabla \nabla}{k^2}\right)\frac{e^{-ik\|r - r'\|}}{\|r - r'\|} 
\end{equation}
and that the electric field $E$ satisfies the radiation condition. Then, for fixed $r'$,
\begin{equation} 
    \overline{G}(r, r'),\,E(r) = \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right), 
\end{equation}
we aim to show that
\begin{equation} 
    \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\partial\mathfrak{B}_R} \hat{n}\cdot[(\nabla\times E(r))\times \overline{G}(r, r') + E(r)\times(\nabla\times\overline{G}(r, r'))]\,\mathrm{d}r = 0,
\end{equation}
where $\mathfrak{B}_R = \{\forall r\in\mathbb{R}^3:\|r\|<R\}$. To
achieve this, I first rewrite the term as follows:
\begin{equation} 
    \hat{n}\cdot E(r) \times(\nabla\times\overline{G}(r, r')) = (\hat{n}\times E(r))\cdot(\nabla\times \overline{G}(r, r')) = -(\nabla\times \overline{G}(r', r)) \cdot (\hat{n}\times E(r)),
\end{equation}
using the fact that$\overline{G}(r, r') = \overline{G}^t(r', r)$ and $\nabla ' = -\nabla$. Similarly,
\begin{equation} 
    \hat{n}\cdot(\nabla\times E(r))\times \overline{G}(r, r') = (\nabla\times E(r))\cdot \overline{G}(r, r')\times\hat{n}.
\end{equation}
Now, since each term in the integrand decays as $\frac{1}{r^2}$​, this decay rate alone is not sufficient for convergence. We must show that their difference decays as $\frac{1}{r^3}$ to ensure the integral vanishes at infinity. For this, I am investigating ways in which these terms might cancel each other to achieve the required rate of decay. That is why I rewrote the terms as a difference of similar expressions.

Aren't you rather trying to study Kirchhoff's integral theorem for vector fields (instead of the extinction theorem)?
